# GraphicsMagick convert fails for fig to jpg

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

I am trying to convert fig files to jpg using GraphisMagick/ImageMagick. When i am trying the basic command "gm convert input.fig output.jpg", it fails with the below error message.
GraphisMagick - gm convert: Unsupported cell type in the matrix (input.fig).
ImageMagick - convert: UnsupportedCellTypeInTheMatrix `input.fig' @ error/mat.c/ReadMATImage/838.
fig2dev(Transfig) - supports to read fig file in imagemagick. How can i check that do i have that libray?. if library not available how can i include it.
I installed grahicsmagick(1.3.25) and imagemagick(6.9.3-0) using yum install in unix machine.

Comment: Could you enlighten me as to what a `fig` file is please? Where does it come from - which application creates it?

Comment: i hope, fig file are vector images. These file already available for our application. Hopefully matlab or some tool generated this.

Comment: `identify -list delegate | grep fig` should tell you if ImageMagick supports `fig` files. Mine says it will use `uniconvertor`

Comment: FIG R FIG graphics format Requires TransFig.

Comment: identify -list delegate | grep fig
        fig =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"

Comment: You can see if your system knows about fig files by convert -list format. If FIG is not listed, then ImageMagick does not know about it, or you have not installed the needed delegate properly or where ImageMagick can find it.

Comment: onvert -list format | grep -i fig. Return empty result. How can i add fig delegate to imagemagick. does anybody aware of how to include fig libraries in imagemagick?

Comment: Can you provide a sample `fig` file please?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of `fig` file format, but some Googling tells me there are 2 possibilities either a proprietary **Matlab** format or vector files related to the `xfig` drawing package.

I am guessing, form the error messages, that **ImageMagick** thinks yours are the former, **Matlab**, variety and is unhappy about reading them, so I thought I'd try and read the other type.

As you haven't provided a sample, I understand that **potrace** can produce `fig` files, so I made a sample PNG file and passed that (as a PNM file) into **potrace** and made a `fig` file:

[image]

```
convert start.png pnm: | potrace --backend xfig - > file.fig
```

That file (`file.fig`) looks like this:

```
#FIG 3.2
#created by potrace 1.14, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017
Portrait
Center
Inches
Letter
100.0
Single
-2
1200 2
0 32 #000000
0 33 #ffffff
6 1125 5286 9075 7913
3 1 0 0 0 32 50 0 20 0.000 0 0 0 4
1264 5385
1264 5513
8936 5513
8936 5385
0
0
0
0
3 1 0 0 0 32 50 0 20 0.000 0 0 0 4
1264 5641
1264 5769
8936 5769
8936 5641
0
0
0
0
3 1 0 0 0 32 50 0 20 0.000 0 0 0 4
1264 5897
1264 6025
8936 6025
8936 5897
0
0
0
0
3 1 0 0 0 32 50 0 20 0.000 0 0 0 4
1264 6152
1264 6280
8936 6280
8936 6152
0
0
0
0
3 1 0 0 0 32 50 0 20 0.000 0 0 0 4
1264 6408
1264 6536
8936 6536
8936 6408
0
0
0
0
3 1 0 0 0 32 50 0 20 0.000 0 0 0 4
1264 6664
1264 6792
8936 6792
8936 6664
0
0
0
0
3 1 0 0 0 32 50 0 20 0.000 0 0 0 4
1264 6920
1264 7048
8936 7048
8936 6920
0
0
0
0
3 1 0 0 0 32 50 0 20 0.000 0 0 0 4
1264 7175
1264 7303
8936 7303
8936 7175
0
0
0
0
3 1 0 0 0 32 50 0 20 0.000 0 0 0 4
1264 7431
1264 7559
8936 7559
8936 7431
0
0
0
0
3 1 0 0 0 32 50 0 20 0.000 0 0 0 4
1264 7687
1264 7815
8936 7815
8936 7687
0
0
0
0
-6
```

So, now we are where would be if you had provided a sample file! And we can get on with an answer...

You can convert a `fig` file into a JPEG without even needing **ImageMagick** like this:

```
fig2dev -L jpeg file.fig result.jpg
```

[image]

You can convert a `fig` file like the above into a PNG like this:

```
 fig2dev -L png file.fig result.png
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. fig2dev will solve the issue but i could not install fig2dev. By default imagemagick is not coming with fig2dev. Could you give me the commands to install fig2dev(either alone or with imagemagick) in unix or mac.

Comment: i followed "http://mcj.sourceforge.net/installation.html#install-transfig" this article to install fig2dev which is unsuccessful.

Comment: I installed it with **homebrew** - which is a brilliant package manager for macOS if you don't already use it. If you have **homebrew**, the command is just `brew install transfig`.

Comment: Mac throws the following error.Error: No available formula with the name "transfig"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: is there a way to add fig2dev or transfig as delegate to imagemagick?

Comment: Your **homebrew** installation doesn't sound very happy! I have no idea what has gone wrong with it. Have you tried `brew update`, `brew upgrade` and `brew doctor`?